# nouveau filling syslog on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, nvidia, nouveau, syslog

I just had 50GBs worth of logs shipped to my ELK stack (sadly expensive). They are all from the same Ubuntu 20.04 Server, with a GTX 1660 installed. This server does not have X11 installed.

I am using the default nouveau driver. All the lines look like this:

`nouveau 0000:0d:00.0: disp: ctrl 00000080`

Any ideas what is causing this, or if I can have this not be stored in syslog?